# How to allow Sign Up In Devise after Invitation was sent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, devise-invitable

When I send an invite to new user via `DeviseInvitable` (e.g. to **eagle@gmail.com**) a new record is created in `User` table with field `email` `==` **eagle@gmail.com**.

Later when I try to Sign Up as a new user and specify an email **eagle@gmail.com** I get an error: `Email has already been taken`.

====

I work on a multi tenant web app where Sign Up means creation of new container within which a **group of users** will work. Administrator of a group can Invite new members to join. BUT a user may not wish to accept invitation to existing group and instead decide to create his own group.
But currently he can not Sign Up because his email address is already in DB...

Is there a way for **eagle@gmail.com** to still Sign Up? (Maybe rejecting invitation or deleting his record from DB by confirming his email address)?

Comment: Well, you can override the default Devise controllers and do whatever you like, really. Work out what you'd like to happen from a user's point of view, then work out the steps you'd need to take in your controller methods to make that happen. It sounds like you may want the 'previously signed up' (for unconfirmed users) error to take you to a new page that lets you choose or create one of your groups, then send a confirmation email.

Comment: Shout if you want any guidance on overriding the Devise controllers.

Comment: Is this changed workflow possible in Devise? Upon unsuccessful Sign Up  I need to redirect a user to my custom page telling him that someone used his email address for invitation and in order to Sign Up he needs at first to confirm his email address. When he confirms it - I will delete his email address from DB (created previously by Invite) so he could Sign Up.

Comment: **A Fader Darkly**, which method should I override in RegistrationsController to catch a moment when email is checked in DB (before I get redirected to a page with `Email has already been taken` msg)

Comment: The controller is defined here: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

Comment: I think the create method is where you need to be.

Comment: I would need to know more about your object domain to offer further guidance on the code, however the original method is relatively simple so I can't imagine you'll have too much trouble.

Comment: Thanks I'll try and then post how it went :)

Answer (score 0):

Override your registrations controller like this:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:user][:email])
    if user && user.invitation_token
      user.destroy
    end
    super       
  end
end
```